# startService() causing UI Thread to Freeze

Tags: android, android-service, ui-thread, foreground-service

In my app I am starting a foreground service and showing a progress dialog to update the user on progress. On certain phones starting the foreground service causes the ui to lag for a few seconds. If I disable the following code, the ui responds fine.

The code to start the service is `applicationContext.startService(FirmwareUpdateService.createUpdateActionIntent(applicationContext, progress));`

If I comment the code above out then nothing freezes.

If I comment the logic inside the service (only shows a foreground notification), it doesn't make a difference.

`private void createUpdateNotification(int progress) {
return new Notification.Builder(this) .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.updating)) .setProgress(MAX_PROGRESS, progress, false) .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.push_notif_icon) .build();
}`

`Notification notification = createUpdateNotification(progress);
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);`

After the first call to start the service, sequential calls don't freeze the UI. Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: On the first call to start the `Service`, the constructor of the `Service` is called and `onCreate()` is called in the `Service`. Do you have any code in there that could take significant amount of time?

Comment: @DavidWasser The only code we have is in `onStartCommand()` and it is to show the notification as shown above.

Comment: post the code in `createUpdateNotification()`

Comment: @DavidWasser 
`return new Notification.Builder(this)
.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.updating))                .setProgress(MAX_PROGRESS, progress, false)                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.push_notif_icon)
.build();`

Comment: In the future don't put code in a comment. You can just edit your original question and add the code there. It is easier to read.

Comment: Sorry, I've no clue what the problem is here.

Comment: @DavidWasser Fixed the issue by using a binder. For some reason calling `startService()` with a different intent but for the same service causes the UI thread lag on older phones.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by using a `Binder` to get a connection to the service. For some reason older Android phones struggle when calling `startService()` with an Intent for the same service but different action.

Edit:
Looks like the main cause of the problem wasn't the service. It was SharedPreferences. We had a lot of `.apply()`s queued up in SharedPreferences. Android seems to flush all of those changes to disk and it holds up the UI thread in doing so.

If you have a lot of SharedPreferences `.apply()`s pending then if you background the app or start a service it blocks the UI thread as it dumps all of the changes to SharedPreferences. I am not sure if this is intended and on what cases Android decides to do that.